# Laravel Pagodabox v-hosts

Tags: laravel, vhosts

OK I have a site works find locally when I set up vhosts as so:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.7>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\public"
ServerName myServer
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

HOWEVER, when I push to pagodabox the only page that works is my home page. When I try to login, register etc I just get a 404 error page. I have the same problem locally if I don't set up vhosts. Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Don't know if you are using Laravel 4, but if so, you can use `php artisan serve` to run you app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no I'm using laravel 3.

Comment: Is `myServer` a real value? If so, and you wanna use it, do you add it to your hosts file?

Comment: Again thanks for your time. Yes, I added it to my hosts file. The site works find locally when I set vhosts as above and add myServer to my hosts file. But I can't get the code to work on pagodabox, if I don't set up vhosts on my local machine I get the same problem as I do on pagodabox.